# How to fix a dead usb port on PS4?

Tags: ps4, controllers

One of the front usb port on my PS4 suddenly stopped working.

Neither charging nor connecting works using a corded controller. The very same controller connects and charge fine when plugged into the other usb port.

Since i have one corded and one cordless controller i wish to have both the ports available to charge the wireless at anytime without unplugging the corded.

What can i try at home before sending it for repair?

Is there any expansion devices to obtain multiple usb ports from the one still alive? Would a powered usb hub work?

Comment: When inserting a USB device into the dead slot, what does it feel like? Is it smooth with relatively little resistance? Does the male end appear to insert as far as the working port? Shine a light in and see if there's any dust or dirt piled up.

Comment: Apparently the look and feel is right and similar to the other one. The connector goes down all the way to the end. Also the inside looks good and the contacts shiny. I will try to clean with compressed air though. thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to test if the USB is truly dead, I would try plugging a USB phone charger into the port. Plug your phone on the other end. If the phone charges, its alive. If the phone does not react (like if you plugged it to a wire that is not wired in anywhere), first check if there is gunk in the port. Flash a flashlight straight in and it should be relatively clean. If it looks relatively clean, your port is truly dead.

From there, you got a few options:

- If on warranty, send your PS4 back to Sony for a repair.
- If not, you could try replacing the port yourself or go to a local geek shop that does repairs. That will very probably void any warranty (its pretty much open heart surgery on your PS4), so the other option is preferable if you got one.

IMO, if you dont have warranty I would not risk it. A switch that big just to bring back a USB port (when you have others you can use) and has chances to kill your console seems very risky.

Comment: In any console service, it should be a kind of cheap repair. Replace USB port it is not rocket science, so you can not be afraid about the big costs of it.

Comment: Doesnt that usually involve connecting new stuff to the motherboard?

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me too, i found the recommendations at the link below very useful
https://careergamers.com/how-to-clean-the-ps4-controller-usb-charging-port/

If the port turns out to be really broken and the problem is only charging two controllers with one port then you can take a look at dualshock twin charging station. There are many available and they are quite affordable.